# Change font of React MUI GridToolbar

Tags: javascript, material-ui

How can I change the font size of GridToolbar

https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/components/#toolbar

````
<DataGrid
  {...data}
  components={{
    Toolbar: GridToolbar,
  }}
/>```

I tried
`sx={{
     '& .MuiDataGrid-gridToolbar': {
     fontSize: 20,
     },                                                      
}}`
````

Answer (score 0):

You are targeting the wrong class. Components inside the MUI `Data Grid Toolbar` are actually buttons. So you need to target `MuiButton` classes to change their font size.

You can either target the `MuiIconButton-root` or `MuiButton-text` class to change the font size.

```
import { DataGrid, GridToolbar } from "@mui/x-data-grid";          

<DataGrid
     {...data}
     components={{
       Toolbar: GridToolbar
     }}
     sx={{ "& .MuiButton-text": { fontSize: 20 } }}
  />
```